# slow RS - SQL Server 2008 express

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, delayed-execution

I'm having an issue with Reporting Services.
Whenever I start the application, loading of the report list and going through folders takes a lot of time (sometimes more than 10 mins), also goes for entering the report itself. After first report is opened then everything works smooth and folders and reports are opened instantly.
RS is running on IIS V6.0. I've set "shut down worker process after being idle" to 480 mins in the application pool.

Any idea is welcome.
Thank you

Comment: this might be better at home on ServerFault... since it hasnt to do with the code in a particular report but with the server structure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the server itself.. defragmentation and registry cleanup solved most of the issues.